# Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations

Tags: nodeos, cleos, eosio-code

I am trying to create an account with different creator NOT EOSIO.
I have configured node config.ini
producer-name = sunny
signature-provider = PUB_KEY=KEY:PRIVATE_KEY

```
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"sunny","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.
```

Here is some important information. I am starting the non-producing node.

```
cleos --print-response create account eosio account1 PUB_KEY PUB_KEY
```

Comment: Can you maybe share the code snippet or command that you are using? I think that you are missing the keys for the account named "sunny".

Comment: I have added some more information there.

Comment: Try to import your account's private key(the creator one) in a wallet